# Query con fechas MySql JpaRepository Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

Buenas tardes estoy haciendo una aplicacion Java con Spring y JPA Data para la persistencia y tengo un pequeño detalle, guardo en una base de datos MySql un registro con un campo fecha, guarda bien pero cuando hago un consulta por fecha no me devuelve nada, pongo codigo:

El campo guarda la fecha de creacion por lo que solo pongo:

```java
Date fecha = new Date();
```

En Mysql se guarda el registro y si hago una consulta desde el Workbench funciona bien.

Cree mi repositorio de la siguiente manera:

```java
@Repository
public interface PruebaRepository extends JpaRepository<Prueba, Integer> {

    List<Prueba> findByFecha(Date fecha);
}
```

y creo un query con la palabra reservada "findBy" y lo implemento de la siguiente manera:

```java
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("root-context.xml");
        PruebaRepository repo = context.getBean("pruebaRepository", PruebaRepository.class);

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        List<Prueba> nota = null;
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        try {
            nota = repo.findByFecha(format.parse("2020-01-06"));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(Prueba n : nota) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
        context.close();
```

y ahi es cuando no devuelve nada como si no encontrara esa fecha o estuviera mal el formato de la fecha, el caso es que si consulto todos con el metodo "findAll()" si devuelve todos, incluso si uso delimitador en otro campo como "estatus" tambien funciona bien, el problema es unicamente con la fecha.

Alguien le ha pasado o sabe a que se debe? de antemano mil gracia.

Comment: Tienes que enseñar la clase @Entity para poder ayudarte

Comment: Verifica en la base de datos el tipo de datos generado por JPA, en el caso de mysql debe de se DATE() y no DATETIME() para que te funcione la consulta de la forma en que pides

Comment: Gracias por su tiempo, ya funciona, y no sabria decir cual era el error simplemente funciono de un momento a otro. Gracias nuevamente